# What is the specific requirement for achievements like "Alone Tonight"?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Season 4 of Diablo 3 we were introduced to a number of achievements with the wording "Reach Greater Rift" x "without the bonuses of any of the following Class sets."

Alone tonight is Greater Rift 15 achievement.

Some have reported that it is possible to get the achievement with a 2 set bonus while others report a 4 set is ok yet I have been unable to reproduce their results.

What is the actual minimum requirement to trigger these achievements?

Answer (score 4):

I have not attempted this myself, but [people are reporting](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/18710646501) that you are not allowed to have **any set bonus from sets listed**.

That means you can wear at most 1 piece from each of those 24 sets (there are some very useful single pieces there, like those that give *+45-60% to skill damage*).
All other sets are fair game - Chantodo's, Bul-Kathos', Bastions of Will, Endless Walk, crafted sets.

There is also a **[bug](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/18704216027)** that allows to grab those Achievements and a Conquest easily. Set items do not provide bonuses to a lifeless corpse, so you just need to die right before your damage over time effects to finish off the Rift Guardian.

Comment: _Disclaimer: The bug can be used by hardcore players, but at their own peril_